# Calling a method in a class through background process

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I want to call a method **DownloadFiles()** in a class **FileDownload**. Where should I call this method. In the below code, I have called in the **bw_DoWork**, but the control is not reaching there. If I declare in Form Load, then the screen rendering freezes even if I use **worker.RunWorkerAsync**.

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
DownloadFile FileDownloadClass = new DownloadFile();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
}

private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        e.Cancel = true;
    else
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(FileDownloadClass.DownloadFiles());
}

private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Cancelled == true))
    {
        this.lblConnectionStatus.Content = " Download Canceled!";
    }

    else if (!(e.Error == null))
    {
        this.lblConnectionStatus.Content = ("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
    }

    else
    {
        this.lblConnectionStatus.Content = "Done!";
    }
}

private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    lblConnectionStatus.Content = FileDownloadClass.StatusMessage;
    progressBar1.Value = FileDownloadClass.TotalKbCompleted;
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

**Edited**

Changed the bw_Work code as below:

```
   private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bw.CancellationPending == true))
            e.Cancel = true;
        else
        {
            FileDownloadClass.DownloadFiles();
            int PercentComplete = int.Parse((FileDownloadClass.TotalBytesReceived / FileDownloadClass.RemoteFileSize * 100).ToString());
            bw.ReportProgress(PercentComplete);
        }
```

From the Form Load event, I am now calling:

```
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

The things have started working fine except that the ReportProgress event is not updating the progress bar value.

**Edited: Added DownloadFile Class Code**

```
    sealed class DownloadFile:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        #region Private Fields
            // These fields hold the values for the public properties.
            private int progressBarValue = 0;
            private int totalKbCompleted = 0;
            private int totalBytesReceived = 0;
            private int remoteFileSize = 0;

            private string fileName = String.Empty;
            private string statusMessage = String.Empty;
        #endregion

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
            {
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
                }
            }

            #region Public Properties
            public int TotalKbCompleted
            {
                get { return this.totalKbCompleted; }

                set
                {
                    if (value != this.totalKbCompleted)
                    {
                        this.totalKbCompleted = value/1024;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalKbCompleted");
                    }
                }                
            }

            public int TotalBytesReceived
            {
                get { return this.totalBytesReceived; }

                set
                {
                    if (value != this.totalBytesReceived)
                    {
                        this.totalBytesReceived = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("TotalBytesReceived");
                    }
                }
            }

            public int RemoteFileSize
            {
                get { return this.remoteFileSize; }

                set
                {
                    if (value != this.remoteFileSize)
                    {
                        this.remoteFileSize = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("RemoteFileSize");
                    }
                }
            }

            public string CurrentFileName
            {
                get { return this.fileName; }

                set
                {
                    if (value != this.fileName)
                    {
                        this.fileName = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentFileName");
                    }
                }
            }

            public string StatusMessage
            {
                get { return this.statusMessage; }

                set
                {
                    if (value != this.statusMessage)
                    {
                        this.statusMessage = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("StatusMessage");
                    }
                }
            }
            #endregion

        public Int16 DownloadFiles()
        {
            try
            {

                statusMessage = "Attempting Connection with Server";

                DoEvents();
                // create a new ftpclient object with the host and port number to use
                FtpClient ftp = new FtpClient("mySite", 21);

                // registered an event hook for the transfer complete event so we get an update when the transfer is over
                //ftp.TransferComplete += new EventHandler<TransferCompleteEventArgs>(ftp_TransferComplete);

                // open a connection to the ftp server with a username and password
                statusMessage = "Connected. Authenticating ....";
                ftp.Open("User Name", "Password");

                // Determine File Size of the compressed file to download
                statusMessage = "Getting File Details";
                RemoteFileSize = Convert.ToInt32(ftp.GetFileSize("myFile.exe"));

                ftp.TransferProgress += new EventHandler<TransferProgressEventArgs>(ftp_TransferProgress);
                statusMessage = "Download from Server";
                ftp.GetFile("myFile.exe", "E:\\Test\\myFile.exe", FileAction.Create);

                // close the ftp connection
                ftp.Close();
                statusMessage = "Download Complete";
                return 1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                return 0;
            }

        }


        private void ftp_TransferProgress(object sender, TransferProgressEventArgs e)
        {
            totalBytesReceived = Convert.ToInt32(e.BytesTransferred.ToString());
            totalKbCompleted = Convert.ToInt32(totalKbCompleted + Convert.ToInt32(totalBytesReceived));
            progressBarValue = totalKbCompleted;
        }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks odd. Why do you start a backgroundworker inside your backgroundworker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never start your "bw" worker. Furthermore, as Daniel commented, you are using another BW inside your "bw" worker. This is pointless.

Just start the "bw" worker inside your MainWindow()
 and inside bw_DoWork call FileDownloadClass.DownloadFiles().

Comment: Well, its not updating because you do your download, then update the progress once (when it's already done) and the imemdiatly declare your worker done. You need to report from within the download method itself, as its going on, not do the download and then report once. Your cancel won't work for the same reason.

Comment: I have defined INotifyPropertyChanged interface in the DownloadFiles class. How to make the properties of that class change the progress bar value in the Form?

Comment: By defined I assume you mean implemented (meaning that you raise the event as the download is progressing). If so, simply subscribe to DownloadFiles.OnPropertyChanged and call bw.ReportProgress from within that eventhandler.

Comment: That itself I am not following. Can you please illustrate? I am using INotify.. for the first time. How to subscribe?

Comment: Please update your question and show how DownloadFiles is implemented. I have  feeling you are not raising any events.

Comment: In ftp_TransferProgress set your values via the Properties insted of the fields so the changed event gets raised, and then in your other class (with the bg worker) subscribe to DownloadFiles.PropertyChanged.

Sample code:
DownloadFiles.PropertyChanged += (o, e) => {
    int PercentComplete = int.Parse((FileDownloadClass.TotalBytesReceived / FileDownloadClass.RemoteFileSize * 100).ToString());
    bw.ReportProgress(PercentComplete);

}
FileDownloadClass.DownloadFiles();

Answer (score 0):

As Steven said, you never start your bw.

Just for testing you can try to use a simple Thread for starting FileDownloadClass.DownloadFiles().